# Can't get response from Express API in k8s-Skaffold from Postman

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, minikube, skaffold

Trying to do something that should be pretty simple: starting up an Express pod and fetch the `localhost:5000/` which should respond with `Hello World!`.

- I've installed `ingress-nginx` for [Docker for Mac](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#docker-for-mac) and [minikube](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#minikube)

  - **Mandatory**: `kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/static/mandatory.yaml`
  - **Docker for Mac**: `kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/static/provider/cloud-generic.yaml`
  - **minikube**: `minikube addons enable ingress`
- I run `skaffold dev --tail`
- It prints out `Example app listening on port 5000`, so apparently is running
- Navigate to `localhost` and `localhost:5000` and get a "Could not get any response" error
- Also, tried `minikube ip` which is `192.168.99.100` and experience the same results

Not quite sure what I am doing wrong here. Code and configs are below. Suggestions?

---

**index.js**

```
// Import dependencies
const express = require('express');

// Set the ExpressJS application
const app = express();

// Set the listening port
// Web front-end is running on port 3000
const port = 5000;

// Set root route
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'));

// Listen on the port
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`));
```

---

**skaffold.yaml**

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v1beta15
kind: Config
build:
  local:
    push: false
  artifacts:
    - image: sockpuppet/server
      context: server
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      sync:
        manual:
        - src: '**/*.js'
          dest: .
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - k8s/ingress-service.yaml
      - k8s/server-deployment.yaml
      - k8s/server-cluster-ip-service.yaml
```

---

**ingress-service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: server-cluster-ip-service
              servicePort: 5000
```

---

**server-deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: server-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: server
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: server
          image: sockpuppet/server
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
```

---

**server-cluster-ip-service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: server-cluster-ip-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: server
  ports:
    - port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
```

---

**Dockerfile.dev**

```
FROM node:12.10-alpine
EXPOSE 5000

WORKDIR "/app"
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

---

**Output from `describe`**

```
$ kubectl describe ingress ingress-service     
Name:             ingress-service
Namespace:        default
Address:          
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<none>)
Rules:
  Host       Path  Backends
  ----       ----  --------
  localhost  
             /   server-cluster-ip-service:5000 (172.17.0.7:5000,172.17.0.8:5000,172.17.0.9:5000)
Annotations:
  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:  {"apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{"kubernetes.io/ingress.class":"nginx"},"name":"ingress-service","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"rules":[{"host":"localhost","http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"serviceName":"server-cluster-ip-service","servicePort":5000},"path":"/"}]}}]}}

  kubernetes.io/ingress.class:  nginx
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age   From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----  ----                      -------
  Normal  CREATE  16h   nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress default/ingress-service
  Normal  CREATE  21s   nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress default/ingress-service
```

---

**Output from `kubectl get po -l component=server`**

```
$ kubectl get po -l component=server
NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
server-deployment-cf6dd5744-2rnh9   1/1     Running   0          11s
server-deployment-cf6dd5744-j9qvn   1/1     Running   0          11s
server-deployment-cf6dd5744-nz4nj   1/1     Running   0          11s
```

**Output from `kubectl describe pods server-deployment`**: Noticed that the `Host Port: 0/TCP`. Possibly the issue?

```
Name:               server-deployment-6b78885779-zttns
Namespace:          default
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               minikube/10.0.2.15
Start Time:         Tue, 08 Oct 2019 19:54:03 -0700
Labels:             app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=skaffold-v0.39.0
                    component=server
                    pod-template-hash=6b78885779
                    skaffold.dev/builder=local
                    skaffold.dev/cleanup=true
                    skaffold.dev/deployer=kubectl
                    skaffold.dev/docker-api-version=1.39
                    skaffold.dev/run-id=c545df44-a37d-4746-822d-392f42817108
                    skaffold.dev/tag-policy=git-commit
                    skaffold.dev/tail=true
Annotations:        <none>
Status:             Running
IP:                 172.17.0.5
Controlled By:      ReplicaSet/server-deployment-6b78885779
Containers:
  server:
    Container ID:   docker://2d0aba8f5f9c51a81f01acc767e863b7321658f0a3d0839745adb99eb0e3907a
    Image:          sockpuppet/server:668dfe550d93a0ae76eb07e0bab900f3968a7776f4f177c97f61b18a8b1677a7
    Image ID:       docker://sha256:668dfe550d93a0ae76eb07e0bab900f3968a7776f4f177c97f61b18a8b1677a7
    Port:           5000/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Tue, 08 Oct 2019 19:54:05 -0700
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-qz5kr (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  default-token-qz5kr:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-qz5kr
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age        From               Message
  ----    ------     ----       ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled  <unknown>  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/server-deployment-6b78885779-zttns to minikube
  Normal  Pulled     7s         kubelet, minikube  Container image "sockpuppet/server:668dfe550d93a0ae76eb07e0bab900f3968a7776f4f177c97f61b18a8b1677a7" already present on machine
  Normal  Created    7s         kubelet, minikube  Created container server
  Normal  Started    6s         kubelet, minikube  Started container server
```

Comment: Put Kubernetes aside for a moment; if you `docker run -p5000:5000 sockpuppet/server`, can you reach the container?

Comment: Yes, that works as expected: server responds with `Hello world!` in Postman.

Comment: Can you show output of the command: `kubectl describe ingress ingress-service` ? And how about k8s app Pods, are they all running: `kubectl get po -l component=server`?

Comment: @mk_sta Thanks, I have updated with output. Loos like the `server` pods are running. I also tried the `server-cluster-ip-service:5000` that popped up. Same result: nada.

Comment: @mk_sta Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, got this sorted out now.

It boils down to the kind of Service being used: `ClusterIP`.

> ClusterIP: Exposes the service on a cluster-internal IP. Choosing this value makes the service only reachable from within the cluster. This is the default ServiceType.

If I am wanting to connect to a Pod or Deployment directly from outside of the cluster (something like Postman, pgAdmin, etc.) *and* I want to do it using a Service, I should be using `NodePort`:

> NodePort: Exposes the service on each Node’s IP at a static port (the NodePort). A ClusterIP service, to which the NodePort service will route, is automatically created. You’ll be able to contact the NodePort service, from outside the cluster, by requesting `<NodeIP>`:`<NodePort>`.

So in my case, if I want to continue using a Service, I'd change my Service manifest to:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: server-cluster-ip-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    component: server
  ports:
    - port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
      nodePort: 31515
```

Making sure to manually set `nodePort: <port>` otherwise it is kind of random and a pain to use.

Then I'd get the `minikube` IP with `minikube ip` and connect to the Pod with `192.168.99.100:31515`.

At that point, everything worked as expected.

But that means having separate sets of development (`NodePort`) and production (`ClusterIP`) manifests, which is probably totally fine. But I want my manifests to stay as close to the production version (i.e. `ClusterIP`).

There are a couple ways to get around this:

1. Using something like [Kustomize](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize) where you can set a base.yaml and then have overlays for each environment where it just changes the relevant info avoiding manifests that are mostly duplicative.
2. Using `kubectl port-forward`. I think this is the route I am going to go. That way I can keep my one set of production manifests, but when I want to QA Postgres with pgAdmin I can do:

   `kubectl port-forward services/postgres-cluster-ip-service 5432:5432`

   Or for the back-end and Postman:

   `kubectl port-forward services/server-cluster-ip-service 5000:5000`

I'm playing with doing this through the `ingress-service.yaml` using `nginx-ingress`, but don't have that working quite yet. Will update when I do. But for me, `port-forward` seems the way to go since I can just have one set of production manifests that I don't have to alter.

**Skaffold Port-Forwarding**

This is even better for my needs. Appending this to the bottom of the `skaffold.yaml` and is basically the same thing as `kubectl port-forward` without tying up a terminal or two:

```
portForward:
  - resourceType: service
    resourceName: server-cluster-ip-service
    port: 5000
    localPort: 5000
  - resourceType: service
    resourceName: postgres-cluster-ip-service
    port: 5432
    localPort: 5432
```

Then run `skaffold dev --port-forward`.